# Cocos2d-x удаление объектов

Tags: c++, cocos2d

Есть такой фрагмент кода.

```
for (auto view : views)
{
    view->update(deltaTime);

    if (view->isDead())
    {
        trash.push_back(view);
        removeChild(view, true);
    }
}
```

Падает с ошибкой после выполнения `removeChild()`. Переходит на брейкпоинт с содержанием

```
//
// delete_scalar.cpp
//
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//
// Defines the scalar operator delete.
//
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <vcruntime_new.h>
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

Стэк вызовов выглядит следующим образом

```
    ucrtbased.dll!00007ffab25ac2f1()    Unknown
    ucrtbased.dll!00007ffab25af8a5()    Unknown
    TankGame.exe!operator delete(void * block) Line 21  C++
    TankGame.exe!operator delete(void * block, unsigned __int64 __formal) Line 16   C++
    TankGame.exe!WorldModel::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int) C++
    TankGame.exe!std::_Ref_count<WorldModel>::_Destroy() Line 153   C++
    TankGame.exe!std::_Ref_count_base::_Decref() Line 113   C++
    TankGame.exe!std::_Ptr_base<WorldModel>::_Decref() Line 339 C++
    TankGame.exe!std::shared_ptr<WorldModel>::~shared_ptr<WorldModel>() Line 567    C++
    TankGame.exe!std::shared_ptr<WorldModel>::operator=(std::shared_ptr<WorldModel> && _Right) Line 555 C++
    TankGame.exe!ZombieModel::~ZombieModel() Line 14    C++
    [External Code] 
>   TankGame.exe!ZombieView::~ZombieView() Line 11  C++
    [External Code] 
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Ref::release() Line 138    C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Node * __ptr64>::erase(__int64 index) Line 443 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Node::detachChild(cocos2d::Node * child, __int64 childIndex, bool doCleanup) Line 1119 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Node::removeChild(cocos2d::Node * child, bool cleanup) Line 1020   C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Sprite::removeChild(cocos2d::Node * child, bool cleanup) Line 778  C++
    TankGame.exe!WorldView::update(float deltaTime) Line 51 C++
    TankGame.exe!GameScene::update(float deltaTime) Line 55 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Scheduler::scheduleUpdate::__l2::<lambda>(float dt) Line 285   C++
    [External Code] 
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Scheduler::update(float dt) Line 861   C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::Director::drawScene() Line 274 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::DisplayLinkDirector::mainLoop() Line 1397  C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::GLViewImpl::OnRendering() Line 482 C++
    libcocos2d_v3.13.1_Windows_10.0.dll!cocos2d::GLViewImpl::Render() Line 474  C++
    TankGame.exe!Cocos2dRenderer::Draw(int width, int height, float dpi, Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayOrientations orientation) Line 137  C++
    TankGame.exe!CocosAppWinRT::OpenGLESPage::StartRenderLoop::__l2::<lambda>(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^ action) Line 272  C++
    [External Code]
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пошагово выполняете программу в отладчике и смотрите, какая проблема возникает.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow судя по коду вызывается деструктор объекта, который при этом пустой

Comment: покажите как вы инициализируете views, и что такое views? в смысле это самостоятельный класс или наследуемый? если самостоятельный, тогда вероятней всего не хватает деструктора, если же он наследуемый к примеру от sprite, тогда нужно смотреть как вы инициализируете его, в таком случае скорее всего не хватает родителя, примерно так: this->removeChild(view, true). И конечно хорошо бы увидеть текст ошибки, а не стек вызовов

Comment: вероятней всего вы удаляете либо уже удалённый чилд(child) либо не из его родитель.